# How to use Google and Ubuntu fonts on Zen theme

Tags: 7, theming

How can I use Ubuntu font and Google fonts on Zen theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try [Google Fonts](http://drupal.org/project/google_fonts).

> This module enables you to add Google Fonts to your site using the Google Font API.
>
> #### Benefits of the Google Font API
>
> - A choice of high quality open source fonts.
> - No Javascript needed, pure CSS!
> - Works in most browsers.
> - Extremely easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it as you would normally:

- For Google Web Fonts copy the `<link>` to your html.tpl.php, above `<?php print $styles; ?>`
- For Ubuntu or any other font just use `@font-face`

Then just apply the font normally in your CSS.